# Return particular result more than once

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to use a where clause to return some data. However I'd like to some pieces of data to be returned more than once based on the contents of a particular property.

To explain further - assume data similar to the following:

```
int objectID
int multipleTimes,
string someData

5|3|"Hello"
6|2|"Bye"
7|1|"Howdy"
```

Basically, when I return this subset of data, I'd like the second one ("Bye") to appear in the results list twice, while the first one would appear thrice.

How would I do this with linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = source.Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.someData, x.multipleTimes))
                   .SelectMany();
```

Returns `List<string>` with `someData` property value repeated.

Shorter version (by BartoszKP):

```
var result = source.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.someData, x.multipleTimes))
```

**Update**

If you want `result` to contain entire object not only `string` value from `someData` property use following:

```
var result = source.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, x.multipleTimes))
```

Comment: That seems correct but still I don't understand the point of objectID property.I guess OP wants something different but question is not clear enough

Comment: That was easier than expected. Wonderful. @Selman22 - I'm going to pick something "randomly" from the results, and some results should have more chance to appear.